# How can I save my Radio button value in SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

This my output

[image]

when the first time open app should display like this but select one radio  button and close open then should display that selected one
EX:- when the user opens the app at the first then should unselect all values, and then the user select grow and click the next button and close the app after reopening again then should display grow as the selected value.

like this
[image]

my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class RadioButtonScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadioButtonScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RadioButtonScreen> createState() => _RadioButtonScreenState();
}

class _RadioButtonScreenState extends State<RadioButtonScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dropdownValueDisease = level;

    checkValueDisease();
  }

  // data which child
  // data which child
  String? dropdownValueDisease;
//   // List of items in our dropdown menu
  String level = 'y';

  //IF "dropdownValueMembers" is empty pass "which" word as a initial value if al ready selected then pass the shared preference value
  checkValueDisease() {
    _getDataDisease();
  }

  _saveDataDisease(String dropdownDiseaseShared) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setString("Disease", dropdownDiseaseShared);
  }

  _getDataDisease() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dropdownValueDisease = sharedPreferences.getString("Disease") ?? level;
    setState(() {});
  }

//
//
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: height * 0.72,
              width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          minLeadingWidth: 1,
                          leading: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.brightness_1,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          title: const Text(
                            "taking",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          ),
                          trailing: Radio(
                            value: "talking",
                            groupValue: level,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                level = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          minLeadingWidth: 1,
                          leading: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.brightness_1,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          title: const Text(
                            "grow",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          ),
                          trailing: Radio(
                            value: "grow",
                            groupValue: level,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                level = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          minLeadingWidth: 1,
                          leading: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.brightness_1,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          title: const Text(
                            "listing ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          ),
                          trailing: Radio(
                            value: "listing",
                            groupValue: level,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                level = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          minLeadingWidth: 1,
                          leading: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.brightness_1,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          title: const Text(
                            "eye",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          ),
                          trailing: Radio(
                            value: "eye",
                            groupValue: level,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                level = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          minLeadingWidth: 1,
                          leading: Icon(
                            Icons.brightness_1,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 10.0,
                          ),
                          title: const Text(
                            "autism",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.3, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          ),
                          trailing: Radio(
                            value: "autism",
                            groupValue: level,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                level = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 0.0,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 160.0,
                height: 35.0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _saveDataDisease(level);
                  
                    },
                    child: const Text('next')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save `dropdownValueDisease` but you should save `level` value:

```
onPressed: () {
     _saveDataDisease(level);
},
```

also in your _getDataDisease you need pass `SharedPreferences` value to `level` not `dropdownValueDisease`:

```
_getDataDisease() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dropdownValueDisease = sharedPreferences.getString("Disease") ?? level;
    level = dropdownValueDisease;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your support bro I edited my code, I mistakenly added "_saveDataLeda" I corrected that Now can you help me to add sharedpreference to this

Comment: Bro it works prefectly .. Thank you so much for your support...

Comment: If you can, can you help me with the save check box value in sharedpreference? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74206658/how-can-i-save-my-checkbox-value-in-sharedpreferences