# How can I save my checkbox value in SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

In this, I used a Agree checkbox and in there is unselecting, when the click  can select check box then value is true, That works perfectly. But I wanna add shared Preferences to this When added that, after the selected word and close the app and reopened again then should show the check box value true that is selected at the last.
like this
[image]

my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AgreeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AgreeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AgreeScreen> createState() => _AgreeScreenState();
}

class _AgreeScreenState extends State<AgreeScreen> {
  // 1st dropdown button
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    valueAgree;
    checkValueAgree();
  }

  // // are you agree button
  String? valueAgree;
  // //boolean value (are you agree)
  bool isChecked = false;

  checkValueAgree() {
    _getDataAgree();
  }

  _saveDataAgree(bool isChecked) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setBool("Agree", isChecked);
  }

  _getDataAgree() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var result = sharedPreferences.getBool("Agree");
    if (result != null) {
      isChecked;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 15.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.brightness_1,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 10,
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Are  you agree",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                    child: Text(
                      'yes',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Checkbox(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                      (states) =>
                          BorderSide(width: 3.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                    value: isChecked,
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        isChecked = value!;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0, top: 150),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 160.0,
                height: 35.0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //do null check 1st

                      _saveDataAgree(isChecked);
                    },
                    child: const Text('next')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here you need pass you `SharedPreferences` value to `isChecked`, because your `Checkbox` work with `isChecked`, you don't need  `String? valueAgree` just remove it:

```
_getDataAgree() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
    var result = sharedPreferences.getBool("Agree");
    if (result != null){
        isChecked = result;
        setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

and change your `_saveDataAgree` to this:

```
_saveDataAgree(bool isChecked) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setBool("Agree", isChecked);
    
  }
```

Comment: bro I added that but sows many errors  I edited the question.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @DasunDola

Comment: Still "A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String?'. "  shows this error

Comment: I updated my answer again, you don't need `valueAgree`, remove it.

Comment: Now no any errors show.But still not work sharedprefernces

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot bout something, check the update.

Comment: Hey.. no need to tell sry. You help me so much..

Comment: I edited the my code but  still display like as same , Still not working sharedPrefences , When select checkbox and close app and reopen again then not selected the check box.

Comment: are you click on next button after checked the box?

Comment: Think at the first time when open app then check box is unselecting.Then user select checkbox then check box values change to ":bool = true". and and click next button after user close the app and reopen, then should selected check box. (bool = true ) value.

Comment: I hope Now you get it bro

Comment: in your last question update I can see you forgot about `isChecked = result;` in _getDataAgree, could you check to see if you add this part or not?

Comment: Ohh... Now my mistake .. And aslo it works perfectly.. Thank you so much bro .. You helped me so much Thank you again bro!

Answer (score 1):

If you save the question as key and the selected item as value it will be good to go.